# "Der Berg ist hoch." Adjektiv oder Adverb?

Tags: grammar

In dem Satz

> Der Berg ist hoch.

ist "hoch" ein Adjektiv oder ein Adverb? Und warum ist dies so?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Es ist ein Adjektiv in prädikativer Verwendung. Das ganze Prädikat lautet hier "ist hoch", welches das Subjekt "Der Berg" genauer beschreibt.

In attributiver Verwendung wäre es "Der hohe Berg".

In diesem Satz beschreibt *hoch* nicht das Verb *sein*, dann wäre es nämlich ein Adverb. Das Verb *sein* ist eine [Kopula](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopula), welches das Subjekt mit der Satzaussage verbindet. Im Englischen wird es daher auch *linking verb* bezeichnet.

Typische Kopulaverben sind *sein*, *werden* und *bleiben*. Es gibt aber noch eine handvoll anderer Verben, die als Kopula verwendet werden, siehe zum Beispiel [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/VollHilfModal/Kopulaverb.html). Den meisten [Definition](https://books.google.de/books?id=EbYwo7aoxVgC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=definition%20nach%20p.eisenberg&source=bl&ots=rB5ptyYw9o&sig=9uTXycHTZjhpB-Tisk6G8eXetR4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qvgIUbHXI864hAeWm4GoDg#v=onepage&q=definition%20nach%20p.eisenberg&f=false) zufolge, sind diese syntaktisch und semantisch nur "Kopula-ähnlich" und werden nicht als Kopula betrachtet. Die Funktionsweise ist aber identisch. Prädikativ verwendete Adjektive werden im Deutschen nicht dekliniert. Vergleiche:

> Die Frau ist hübsch. (Prädikativ mit Kopula)
>
> Die Frau sieht hübsch aus. (Prädikativ mit Kopula-ähnlichem Verb)
>
> Die hübsche Frau ... (Attributiv - ohne Prädikat kein vollständiger Satz)

Comment: Syntaktisch besteht aber kein Unterschied - oder gibt es ein Beispiel, wo sich das prädikative Adverb 'äußerlich' nicht wie ein Adverb verhält?

Comment: @Martin Da im Deutschen Adverb und Adjektiv meistens identisch sind, gibt es äußerlich in der Tat keinen Unterschied. Im Englischen ist das anders. "His voice is beautiful" vs "He sang beautifully" Wenn du nun ein Wortpaar im Deutschen findest, wo sich Adjektiv und Adverb unterscheiden, gilt das auch für's Deutsche ;)