# Word order for "los" in "Was ist denn hier los?"

Tags: word-order, adverb

This quote, like many that I mention, is from the film "Der Untergang."

"Was ist denn hier los?"

My question is why "hier" comes before "los" and not the other way around? Please provide an example sentence as well if possible.

As I understand the standard TMP (time, manner, place for adverbs)

I think "los" is both an adverb and adjective but here is modifying "ist" so it must be an adverb. And if that is correct, wouldn't it be in the "manner" catagory and come before "hier" which is a "place"

Or now that I think about it, could there be a verb I'm not aware of? Los sein would make sense but Linguee didn't pull anything up.

Also, excuse my quotation craziness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*los* is a regular adjective meaning *off* (in the sense of *unleashed* or *detached*). The basic idiomatic expression using *los* is the following sentence:

> Etwas ist los.
> *Something is unleashed/moving (figuratively: going on)*.

*los* does not become an adverb here as the sentence is simply assigning the attribute *los* to the subject *etwas*. *los* is an adjective used [predicatively](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6015/der-berg-ist-hoch-adjektiv-oder-adverb). Unless used as a poetical synonym for *to exist* or *to live*, *sein* will never imply an adverb.

Your question "*Was ist denn hier los?*" is asking about the *etwas* being *los*, so *los* is still a predicative adjective. There are several positions where the location *hier* might be inserted:

> 1. Was ist denn hier los?
> 2. Was ist hier denn los?
> 3. Was ist denn los hier? *(rather offensive)*

Note that (depending on pronunciation, though), this is rather a rhetorical question. If the speaker is not addressing a specific person and emphasizing the word *hier* in sentence 1 or 2, they are likely expressing outrage about the situation they just encountered. Besides, variant 3 is usually used to eagerly ask for silence or when criticizing somebody in a rough way.

By the way, there are a few more important idioms arising from modifying the word order:

> Hier ist (vielleicht) etwas los!
> *Wow, there is quite something going on here!*
>
> Ist hier etwas los?
> *Is something wrong/going on here?*  or *Is it fun here?*
>
> (Irgend)etwas ist hier los.
> *Something is wrong here [but I don't yet know what it is].*

Actually, we are still not finished here. This is one of the most versatile and "pronunciation-sensitive" expressions in the German language.

Comment: That is an amazingly detailed answer! I love the amount of example sentences you used and even going so far to show the different meanings through word order choice, idiomatic usage, etc... If only I could rate the answer higher :) Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think the comma is correct in "Was ist denn los, hier". Newspapers (who are at the forefront of putting stuff behind the verb) pretty much never use a comma there. Example: "Der Sachbearbeiter hat sich geärgert über die vielen Anträge."

Comment: Right, I deleted the comma.

Comment: Great answer although I kinda disagree with calling it an adjective. It seems to me more like a degenerate adjective that formed a kind of composite verb … although evidence pointing against that is *kann hier je etwas los sein?* where it should be *lossein* if it's a composite verb (cf *Wenn du dich lossagst …*). I'm not sure about it though, I could be badly wrong. If *los* is indeed an adjective, it is a very degenerate one, as was then asked and answered in the [other question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22561/is-los-really-an-adjective). answered

Comment: I was not sure either, but according to Duden, the *los* in "Was ist los" is listed as an adjective. There is another *los* which is indeed an adverb, but it seemed not to be applicable here.