# Stellung der Worte „hier“ und „los“

Tags: word-order

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Sätzen?

> Was ist denn los hier?
>   Was ist denn hier los?

Es geht um die Stellung der Worte *hier* und *los*.

Comment: Die Antwort von [Œlrim  Word order for “los” in “Was ist denn hier los?”](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/22559/2120) geht in den Punkte 2 und 3 hierauf ein  Der Auffassung dass "Was ist denn los hier?" agres ssiver als "Was ist denn hier los?" zu verstehen ist möchte ich mich anschließen.

Answer (score 2):

Das macht keinen Unterschied.

Die beiden Sätze haben dieselbe Bedeutung. Je nach Kontext können sie allerdings besser oder auch schlechter klingen. Der Sinn verändert sich dabei aber nicht.