# Adjective declension + werden?

Tags: adjective-ending

"In Wirklichkeit warten wir nicht, bis die Hände oder andere Körperteile auf natürliche Weise **trocken** werden".

Why in this sentence the adjective ("trocken") doesn't have any ending? I thought that in this case the adjective should have got the ending, which is dictated by plural nouns. So, it could be this way: "... bis die Hände oder andere Körperteile aud natürliche Weise **trockene** werden". Here I have applied the Nominative case ending of plural adjectives when they are used without any article.

Comment: The adjective "trocken" relates hier not to "Hände" but to "werden".

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with a simple sentence.

> Die Hände sind trocken.

When an adjective is used as complement of the copular verb (here *to be*), it's not declined.

*Werden* (*to become*) is another copular verb.

> Die Hände werden trocken.

In your sentence the structure is more complicated but this doesn't change that *trocken* is just the complement of *werden*.

More on copular verbs (in German) in a related question: ["Der Berg ist hoch." Adjektiv oder Adverb?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6015/1224)

Comment: Maybe you could include in your answer that adjectives aren't marked in German when they become adverbs. In contrary, it's the absence of any ending/marking that makes them an adverb.

Comment: @Janka Except, it's not an adverb.